# ASP.NET MVC Subform data not posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This seems simple enough but I am missing something:

Model:

```
public class MainModel
{

   public SubModel oSubmodel = new Submodel();

....

}
```

View:

```
@model myApp.Models.MainModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form"}) 
{

     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.oSubmodel.prop1

     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.oSubmodel.prop1

}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(MainModel oModel)
 {
      ....
      string prop = oModel.prop <-----------ok
      string prop1 = oModel.oSubmodel.prop1   <----------null
  }
```

The m.oSubmodel.prop1 data is display correctly in the view. When the data is posted back to the controller MainModel values are passed correctly, however - all submodel values are null.

Anybody give any insight?

Comment: What does your controller method look like? I had the same problem some time ago... see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755928/how-to-let-the-post-action-method-take-a-subobject-of-the-original-viewmodel-as-a

Comment: Thanks - I added the controller info. Looking now at the question you referenced. But mine seems a much easier requirement. I am pretty sure this is me being dumb.

Comment: You're sure the values are actually passed with the request? You can check this with fiddler...

Comment: Well the values are being passed to the view. I see them displayed.. But yes I nothing is posted back...

Comment: I meant in post back. What are the id's of the input fields that are generated on your view?

Comment: IDs are oSubmodel_prop1 (oSubmodel underscore prop1) etc. Looking at fiddler the value is there in the postback oSubmodel.prop1 = "some value"

Comment: strange... that must be an issue then with the modelbinder... I'm afraid that means downloading the mvc source code and get your hands dirty ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Right OK. My Bad. The subModel need to be exposed as property off the main model for binding to work correctly on post:

So

```
public class MainModel
{

   public SubModel oSubmodel = new Submodel();

....

}
```

becomes:

```
public class MainModel
{

   public SubModel oSubmodel { get; set; }

....

}
```

Binding then works great. Thanks to those that responded.